# Finding $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k$ using summation by parts

Tags: calculus, summation

This is another exercise from Smoryński's *Logical Number Theory*; not being a mathematician, I'm a bit new to this finite difference stuff, so, please, bear with me! In a previous exercise, Smoryński asked us to prove the following formula for summation by parts:

> $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)g(k) = g(n)(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} [\Delta g(k) (\sum\limits_{i=0}^k f(i))]$

Next, he wants us to apply this formula to derive $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. I've tried but I obviously got something wrong. First, note the obvious $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 1 = n+1$ and $\Delta k = 0$ for $k$ constant. Thus, I got:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 1 \times k = n (\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 1) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}[\Delta k \sum\limits_{i=0}^k 1] = n(n+1) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}0 = n(n+1) - 0 = n(n+1)$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\Delta k \equiv \Delta g(k) = (k+1) - k = 1$

Comment: @Winther - Got it! $\Delta k = 0$ if $k$ is a constant *function*, not if $k$ is a constant. Is that right?

Comment: Right! Let $g(k) = k$; then $\Delta g(k) = (k+1)-k = 1$.

Comment: The book you are reading is a very nice one.

Comment: @Winther - So, the last sum simplifies to $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(1 \sum\limits_{i=0}^k 1) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^k 1$, right? But isn't this $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)$? Is there any other to simplify the sum?

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Yea, it's pretty good. It goes a lot more into the mathematical details of some things (e.g. Gödel's Beta function) than most logic books do. Still, not being a mathematician, I'm struggling a bit with it (but it's been worth it!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(k)=1$ and $g(k)=k$.  Then we have

$$\begin{align}
S&\equiv \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(k)g(k)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\\\\
&=g(n)\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left((g_{k+1}-g_k)\sum_{i=0}^{k}f(i)\right)\\\\
&=n(n+1)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}1\\\\
&=n(n+1)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)\\\\
&=n(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\\\\
&=n(n+1)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\\\\
2S&=n(n+1)\\\\
S&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Nice! I didn't think about adding $S$ to both sides in order to eliminate that sum. Very helpful.

Comment: @Nagase  Thanks.  Yes, $S=x-S\implies S=\frac12 x$.